# Custom diagnostics views in Nancy

Tags: c#, nancy

In Nancy .NET web service, is there a simple way to override and extend the visual interface default diagnostics dashboard? There are a bunch of `.sshtml`, `.js`, `.css` files bundled with the NuGet package, but how to customise the NancyModule for diagnostics and replace those files?
What is the recommended way?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are some hooks to modify output of diagnostic info. If you scroll towards the bottom of the NancyFx diagnostic wiki, there's a few sections on overriding the template output, and changing default behavior of some of the default configurations. Not sure if it's quite what you're looking for, but it's a good start.  Link here:  https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Diagnostics